# Holomorphic complex parameter integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

Maybe it is a basic question, but I can not find an answer in standard textbooks or at StackExchange.

> Let $D\subseteq \mathbb C$ be an open set and $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb C^n$. Further, let $f:D\times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb C$ be a function, which is holomorphic with respect to its first variable $\eta\in D$ and $f(\eta,x)$ absolutely integrable on $\Omega$ with respect to its second variable for all $\eta\in D$. What are the conditions that also the parameter integral
>   $$ F(\eta) = \int_\Omega dx f(\eta,x) $$
>   is holomorphic in $\eta\in D$? What are the conditions if one replace "holomorphic" by "meromorphic"?

I would guess, that in order to use Cauchy-Riemann equations, one also has to claim the deriviatives $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial\eta_1}$ and $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial\eta_2}$ to be absolutely integrable?

Comment: Replace $ \int_\Omega dx f(\eta,x)$ by the sequence of its approximate Riemann sum, those are finite sums of analytic functions thus analytic, the key is to check if it converges (locally) uniformly, in which case the limit is analytic. Yes the integrability of the derivative is sufficient for the holomorphicity.

Comment: @reuns: But does this also work for improper Riemann integrals e.g. like $\Omega=\mathbb R_+^n$ or other non-Riemann but Lebesgue-integrable functions?

Comment: In complex analysis one can often use Morera's theorem to show that parameter-dependent integrals are holomorphic. Then you don't need derivatives, but you need that the function $F$ is continuous, and that the assumptions for Fubini's theorem are satisfied for $f$ (with respect to path integrals in the $\eta$-variable).

Comment: @Lukas Geyer: I see and the assumptions for Fubini are included in the previous conditions. As considered it is $\int_\Omega dx |f(\eta,x)| < \infty$ and therefore the integral $\oint_{\partial\Delta} d\eta \int_\Omega dx |f(\eta,x)| $ does also exist. Thank you for answering my question.